# Adding Number Validation to a String

Tags: java, android, android-studio, validation, android-edittext

I currently have 2 editText fields which are set to Type: Number where the user can input a number value, I have added these editText fields as a String in order to pass these values to an SQL Database. I was wondering how I could add number validation to these fields where the user is required to input: More than or equal to, as well as less than and equal to. See example below:

```
     String number = ((EditText)findViewbyId(R.id.text_numberExample)).getText().toString();
     // How would I validate where the user is required to input number values between a range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a java implementation. This idea is very similar to android. For jave, instead of using `((EditText)findViewbyId(R.id.text_numberExample)).getText().toString()`, I use `Scanner` for taking input.

- After taking input, check if it is a number or string(like "Hello"). If it is a string like `Hello` then, it throws an exception. Similarly, if it is a valid number but out of your desire range, then it also throws a custom exception.
- Both case, it force user for valid input.
- Now you convert thing value to `string` again.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringToNumberWithValidation{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
        boolean flag = true;
        Long number = null;
        while(flag){
            System.out.print("Insert Number Example: ");
            String numberString = in.next();
            
            try {
                number = Long.parseLong(numberString);
                numberValidator(number);
                flag = false;
            }catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(number);

    }
    
    static void numberValidator(Long number) {
        Long min = (long) 10;
        Long max = (long) 100;
        if(number >= min && number <= max ) {
            return;
        }
        throw new NumberFormatException("Number Out of Range");
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter
{
    private final int min;
    private final int max;
    private final UtilityListener utilityListener;

    public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max,UtilityListener utilityListener)
    {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.utilityListener = utilityListener;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
        try
        {
            int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());

            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                utilityListener.getItem("Value cannot exceed " + max);
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ignored)
        {
            utilityListener.getItem("NumberFormatException");
        }
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

here is Listener

```
public interface UtilityListener
{
    void getItem(Object object);
}
```

and in activity

```
binding.editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax(1,10, object ->
        {
            String message = (String) object;

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        })});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get int value by using https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html

And then manually chack if this value si in your range

Comment: I'm not using Kotlin, it is java, but thanks for your response

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)
This is for java

Comment: Thanks for this, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

first make a regex in string like this

```
String limitValue = "[1-9]";
```

then use if to match

```
        if(number.matches(limitValue)){
            Log.v("OK","Number is in limit");
        }else{       
            Log.v("NOT OK","Number is not in limit");
        }
```